# Correlation of vectors contained in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, python-2.x

I have a nested dict with the next structure:

```
{Cell_name_1 : {KPI_name_1: [value1, value2, ..., valueN], 
                KPI_name_2: [value1, value2, ..., valueN], 
                ..., 
                KPI_name_N: [value1, value2, ..., valueN]}, 
 Cell_name_2 : {KPI_name_1: [value1, value2, ..., valueN], ...}, 
 Cell_name_N : {....}}
```

I want to check the correlation (I have this method defined already, so it's an auxiliaryfunction) between the vectos contained in the different cells. Let's say:

```
vector_1 = [64.0, 66.0, 53.5, 52.1, 54.0] #[values from KPI_name_1 from Cell_name_1]
vector_2 = [84.0, 86.0, 63.5, 72.1, 24.0] #[values from KPI_name_2 from Cell_name_2]

correlation(vector_1, vector_2)
```

I have tried different ways of looping over the dictionaries (normal for loops, classic loops with while and conditions, etc), but I do not find the way to get what I need.

As an example, the code is something like this:

```
dic_sem = {'16895555': {'KPI_name_1': [64.0, 66.0, 53.5, 52.1, 54.0], 
                        'KPI_name_2': [54.0, 56.0, 23.5, 32.1, 84.0]}, 
           '16894444': {'KPI_name_1': [84.0, 86.0, 63.5, 72.1, 24.0], 
                        'KPI_name_2': [24.0, 26.0, 63.5, 92.1, 84.0]}}
```

`'16895555'` and `'16894444'` are the different `Cell_name's`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the dictionary and create a dictionary of the cellnames e.g. `KPI_name_1` to a list of lists which contains your vectors

```
from collections import defaultdict

vectors = defaultdict(list)

#Iterate over the values
for value in dic_sem.values():
    #Create your vectors dictionary
    for k, v in value.items():
        vectors[k].append(v)

print(dict(vectors))
```

The output will be

```
{'KPI_name_1': [[64.0, 66.0, 53.5, 52.1, 54.0], [84.0, 86.0, 63.5, 72.1, 24.0]], 
'KPI_name_2': [[54.0, 56.0, 23.5, 32.1, 84.0], [24.0, 26.0, 63.5, 92.1, 84.0]]}
```

You can then iterate over the values of this dictionary and call `correlation` accordingly

```
for value in vectors.values():
    print(value[0], value[1])
    #correlation(*value)
```

The output here will be

```
[64.0, 66.0, 53.5, 52.1, 54.0] [84.0, 86.0, 63.5, 72.1, 24.0]
[54.0, 56.0, 23.5, 32.1, 84.0] [24.0, 26.0, 63.5, 92.1, 84.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `itertools.product` can be of help here:

```py
  import itertools
  import numpy as np

  # Get vector names (assuming keys present in all cells)
  field_names = list(dic_sem.values())[0].keys()

  # Precompute all pairs of cells 
  all_cell_pairs = list(itertools.product(dic_sem.keys(), dic_sem.keys()))

  corr = {}
  for field in field_names: 
      corr[field] = np.reshape([correlation(dic_sem[c1][field], dic_sem[c2][field]) for c1, c2 in all_cell_pairs], (len(dic_sem), -1))
```

Note that we do here more than twice the computations necessary: correlation matrix is symmetric so enough to compute only upper or lower triangle (e.g. using `itertools.combinations`), excluding diagonal (which is equal to 1). But the above should give the direction..

Comment: Im sorry, but I can't use numpy or itertools libraries.